# API Blueprint on-page links in Resource group?

Tags: html, api, markdown, apiblueprint, apiary

I'm writing a product data API in Blueprint and I'd like to provide a link in the `styleNumber` parameter to a `# Group Value References` beneath the Resource.

```
## GET Details for products that match any combination of the parameters below [/productservice/products/{?language,styleNumber}]

### Product Service (Products) [GET]
+ Parameters

    + language (array[string],optional)-_One or more 2 letter language codes ([ISO 639-1](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) format, comma separated)_
    + styleNumber (array[string],optional)-_One or more 5 digit proprietary product style IDs (comma separated) See **[Value References](#Group Value References)**._
```

I was able to insert a working link to an external page in the `language` parameter, but neither a traditional markdown on-page link nor a link to a defined html name seem to be semantically valid to Apiary.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    ... See [Value References](/reference/value-references)._
```

It has to be the path to the actual heading and not the title.

URI cannot contain spaces etc., which is why what you have isn’t designed to work. I believe `#value-references` is meant to work as the URI anchor, but it doesn’t work in Apiary Documentation. Perhaps a bug, but maybe design.